# Reading multiple text files java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having trouble on reading multiple text files to fit into one scanner for example I have multiple text files that are named `text1.txt`, `text2.txt` etc... I'm trying to make it so that once the user enters which text file number they want it will bring up that data via arrays.

```
File txt = new File("text.txt");

void readTextFiles() throws IOException {
String line[] = new String[100];
Scanner readTextFiles= new Scanner(txt);

while (readTextFiles.hasNextLine()) {
  line[q] = readTextFiles.nextLine();
  if (line[q].trim() != "") {
    String item[] = line[i].split(" ");
    time[q] = item[0];
    date[q] = item[1];
  }
  q++;

}
readTextFiles.close();
}
```

my logic works like this but its a code error:

```
File txt= new File("txt" + textFileNumber + ".txt");
int textFileNumber=0;`
```

Comment: what is the problem you got ?

Comment: i need to use 1 method that can work with multiple text files so when a user wants to read text file 2 the method can get that specific file and if it wants to read text file 3 it can get that file in the same method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, the error you got is because the initialisation of the local variable does not precede it's use. You need to declare the `textFileNumber` before its usage in the string concatenation.
Further you are implementing this functionality as a method. So why not make the file number a method parameter?

```
public void readTextFiles(int fileNumber){
    File txtFile = new File("text" + fileNumber + ".txt");
    //logic
}
```

Comment: thats it worked didnt know you had to put it into a method cheers